# "not authorized on config to execute command" Error when rebuild path analyzer from historical data

Tags: path-analyzer

When trying to rebuild path analyzer from historical data the following error appears in log file:

```
    16916 2016:09:21 08:50:19 ERROR [Path Analyzer] BuildMapAgent failed
Exception: MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException
Message: Command 'count' failed: not authorized on config to execute command { count: "chunks", query: { ns: "usd_analytics.Interactions" } } (response: { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on config to execute command { count: \"chunks\", query: { ns: \"usd_analytics.Interactions\" } }", "code" : 13 })
Source: MongoDB.Driver
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.CommandOperation`1.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult](IMongoCommand command, ReadPreference readPreference, IBsonSerializer resultSerializer, IBsonSerializationOptions resultSerializationOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult](IMongoCommand command, ReadPreference readPreference)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Count(CountArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Tasks.MongoDbSequenceFactory2.CreateInteractionSequence(InteractionHistoryRangeDefinition range)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Tasks.MongoDbSequenceFactory2.GetSequence[TKey](ObjectRangeDefinition range)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Internals.SchedulerFactory.InitializeScheduler[TWorkItem](Guid taskId, ObjectRangeDefinition range)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.TaskManager.StartDistributedProcessing[TWorkItem](ObjectRangeDefinition query, DistributedWorker`1 worker, TaskOptions options)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.BuildMapAgent.ScheduleRebuild(List`1 definitions)
```

Any ideas of how to solve this error?

Comment: Do you have any more information to help identify the error here? What have you looked at so far to debug this?

Comment: Yogesh Patel solution solved my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using shared database user for mongoDB? Make sure to grant it read rights.

Refer:
https://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2015/04/09/sitecore-8-xdb-using-shared-users-on-mongodb/